# PayPal Smart Buttons (Subscription) using paypal.FUNDING.CARD button update_client_config_error

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm implementing the Paypal Smart buttons to my website for subscription, with the following code:

```
paypal.Buttons({
    commit: false,
       createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
         return actions.subscription.create({
           plan_id: 'P-4688500211745173CL4LO52Y'
         });
       },
       onCancel: function (data) {
       },
       onApprove: function(data, actions) {
       }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

I subscribed via Debit Or Credit Card (paypal.FUNDING.CARD button). It returns the JSON data for subscription:

```
{
  billingToken: "BA-28952229JX1690450"
  facilitatorAccessToken: "A21AAF2g9HmhCrpdlvKv82KzTOL7s- 
  h7udVM63Jx6PoEQJvhRHUKZXuxdEewBWbAlh7Tta44GREGBKPqydgSaWBdTZBInLTMA"
  orderID: "91D07990YA8971453"
  subscriptionID: "I-EN0D6RAEFN8R"
}
```

But when I need to downgrade or upgrade the current subscription using https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-EN0D6RAEFN8R/revise API endpoint base on the PayPal docs. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/subscriptions/add-capabilities/revise-subscriptions/

The PayPal window automatically close and I get the error: "Uncaught Error: Api: /smart/api/billagmt/subscriptions/I-EN0D6RAEFN8R/cartid returned status code: 500 (Corr ID: e0a949aefc835)"

This is my code to revise subscription:

```
paypal.Buttons({
    commit: false,
       createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
         return actions.subscription.revise('I-EN0D6RAEFN8R', {
           plan_id: 'P-0P5665289K689682KL4MD5PQ'
         });
       },
       onCancel: function (data) {
       },
       onApprove: function(data, actions) {
       }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Note: Subscribing via PayPal Account (paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL button) doesn't have the error that I'm encountering when I subscribe via PayPal Credit Or Debit Card. I can also upgrade or downgrade the subscription plan using the revise code above.

Anybody experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior makes sense, you need to log into a PayPal account to approve revising a subscription.

When there is nothing to log into, there is no way to approve a revision on the client side.  Your own authorized server-side API call is necessary to modify/cancel it. You can have the user sign up again (new profile) and cancel the original one.

Comment: I have skipped the part in their documentation that revising of current subscription when you subscribe using debit or credit doesn't need to use the paypal smart button. Just call directly to the revise API. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is this update/revise call: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_revise , but it is limited in what you can change

Comment: @PrestonPHX When a customer is upgrading/downgrading a subscription, How do we ,the merchant, know if the customer used their paypal account for the subscription or if they were a guest and utilized the credit/debit card? Depending on one or the other would dictate if I need to show paypal buttons for them to approve the upgrade/downgrade, or if I can use the restful api to upgrade/downgrade the subscription?